# Status Entities in .NET Core Entity Framework - suggested implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am new to full stack software development, and I have an assignment to create a simple full stack web app in .NET Core, Entity Framework Core (when it comes to the back-end part), which would store some employee data. Now, let's say I have an Employee entity. We also need to implement the Employee's position in some way (an employee can have the position of a back-end developer, front-end developer, project manager etc.). That's why I have also created this EmployeePosition class, so that there is an EmployeePosition property in Employee. I also have other similar status enitities like the EmployeePosition in the app.

EmployeePosition would then be seeded to a separate table in the database, and thus it can be applicable to any company that "would use" this app (just use different seed data). I will use a legacy database for seeding.

Now it seems that this would work, but it also seems a bit too crude for me, because whenever I would need to do an operation with the status in the repository, I would have the use the magic Id number of the status, or hardcode the status Name property somewhere in a method (if I don't have a smarter workaround for the given operation), for instance "Switch(Position.Name) case "front-end": do stuff" etc.

Could I maybe get a suggestion or direction on how to implement this better, am I on a good track here?

Would it be better to actually use enums as data types inside of EmployeePosition, any suggestions on how to implement that? Considering that I have to use the legacy database for seeding, I would have to somehow create my enums out of the legacy file.

```
public class Employee
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Image { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public EmployeePosition Position { get; set; }
```

```
public class EmployeePosition
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have conflicting requirements unfortunately. You say that your program is "status-agnostic":

> EmployeePosition would then be seeded to a separate table in the database, and thus it can be applicable to any company that "would use" this app (just use different seed data).

And yet, it's really not:

> Because whenever I would need to do an operation with the status in the repository, I would have the use the magic Id number of the status, or hardcode the status Name property somewhere in a method (if I don't have a smarter workaround for the given operation), for instance "Switch(Position.Name) case "front-end": do stuff" etc.

So one of those requirements has to "win". Either your code knows what the different statuses are (and so different seed data wouldn't work) or it doesn't.

**If the first requirement is more important:**

Keep your code as it is, you have a perfectly reasonable model for N number of statuses where they aren't known ahead of time, nor is any logic specific to a given entry

**If the second requirement is more important:**

Switch to an enum. You don't want magic numbers *or* strings floating around in your code. As you mention, you'll need to map each existing data row into one of the predefined enum members.

Comment: It makes more sense now, and I see why. Is there a way I could use this EnumBuilder Class to achieve both - to create Enums out a file that I have? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.enumbuilder?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @Armino I don't see how that buys you anything. The code still either does or does not need to know about the actual values to perform logic. It could save you a bit of "write time" to create the enum I guess, but in reality it shouldn't be that hard to just make the enum from your existing data, especially if there is logic (as you wouldn't want massive switch statements)

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is create an `Enum` for employee positions.

```
public enum EmployeePosition
{
   Backend = 0,
   Frontend = 1,
   DBA = 2,
}
```

And your employee entity

```
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Image { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public EmployeePosition Position { get; set; } 
}
```

Then you can use

```
If (Employee.Position == EmployeePosition.Backend)
{
     // your logic.
}
```

Comment: You cannot extend the list of positions, without changing your code.
Might be OK, might be not.